# Magento 2: Can anyone explain when the js-translation.json comes into picture

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to change all the text on the checkout page. I have refer many documents.

But I want to understand flow that it will work.

Has anyone idea about it?

I want to do customization on checkout page.

[image]

Comment: you have to translate JS error message? can you elaborate more what do you want to translate?

Comment: @ChiragPatel please check image. i have added in myquestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change text using **i18** CSV translation method.

In your theme directory (For example)

> magento2/app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange/i18n/en_US.csv

Add the following like.

```
 "Payment Method:", "Your text"
 "Review & Payments", "Your text"
 "Apply discount", "Your text"
```

Run the deploy command to get localization changes:

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

For more reference [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Those texts above using js translation which loaded to local storage "mage-translation-storage"

[image]

Your text could be found and translated by those lines, you could add it to theme i18n csv or create a separated translation package from /app/i18n

```
"Payment Method:","Payment Method:",module,Magento_Checkout
"Review & Payments","Review & Payments",module,Magento_Checkout
"Apply Discount Code","Apply Discount Code",module,Magento_SalesRule
```

The main point of this which you think this should not work because your deployment script.

As mentioned **[here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7525)** you have to separate the lines of deployment scrips

So instead of using:

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE it_IT fr_FR es_ES
```

Use

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES
```

Here is my sample deployment script when I work with multiple languages project

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade; 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -t Vendor/FrontTheme -t Vendor/AdminTheme;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE -t Vendor/FrontTheme;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT -t Vendor/FrontTheme;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```